# Numbering of figures and tables by section if subsection=0

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am currently working on numbering my tables and figures according to the subsections which looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}


\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\begin{figure} % I would like this figure to be numbered 1.1 as opposed to 1.0.1
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pictures/Logo.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\subsection{xyz}
\begin{figure} % I would like this figure to be numbered 1.1.1 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pictures/Logo.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\section{bar}


\end{document}
```

Basically, whenever I include a table or figure before entering a subsection, the numbering comes out to x.0.y. Is there any way to change the numbering of the tables/figures to \counterwithin{figure}{section}, so it counts only the sections when subsection=0 and to nubering by \counterwithin{figure}{subsection} if subsection>0?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you could also add 1 to that counter `\stepcounter{figure}`, so `y.0.x` become `y.1.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will confuse your readers, particularly if a figure or table floats past the subsection it refers to. Anyway…

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{chngcntr} % not needed with recent LaTeX

\counterwithin*{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{table}{subsection}
% * means don't change the representation, because we'll do it now
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \thesubsection.%
  \else
    \thesection.%
  \fi
  \arabic{figure}%
}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \thesubsection.%
  \else
    \thesection.%
  \fi
  \arabic{table}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

Some text.

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label-a}
\end{figure}

\subsection{xyz}

Some text.

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label-b}
\end{figure}

\section{bar}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Redefine numbering for that figure.

[image: image of captions]

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove [demo] 
\usepackage[british]{babel} 

\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}


\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\begin{figure}\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}} % <-- added this
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pictures/Logo.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\subsection{xyz}
\begin{figure} % I would like this figure to be numbered 1.1.1 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pictures/Logo.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\section{bar}


\end{document}
```